# Suggestions for guided NLP online courses - Beginner 101

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-mining, text

I would like to know from the data science community here for suggestions on nlp courses.

I am new to NLP area and would like to take up a course which covers from basic to advanced concepts such as tokenization to embeddings, GPT-3, transformers etc

My aim is to become a Applied NLP expert (and I don't intend to invent any new algos). So, basically am trying to find a course where they can teach us existing algos, recent advancements, variety of use-cases etc in NLP

Is there any courses that you would recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend two course which focus on code first approach and which will help you understand concepts by getting your hands dirty. Both of these courses contains code and video resources.

- [Fast.ai NLP](https://www.fast.ai/2019/07/08/fastai-nlp/)
- [Hugging Face NLP](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter0/1?fw=pt)

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Manning's course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/), the course is available for free on youtube. However it doesn't really start from zero, it's quite advanced imho.